# Zend 'Pluginpaths' outside the zend-library folder

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins

In my Zend project I have built the **LS_Controller_Plugin_LangSelector**.It is located inside the following folder structure.

```
/library
 /LS
   /Controller
     /Plugin
       LangSelector.php
```

In my config.ini file I just added the following lines and everything works like a charme.

```
autoloaderNamespaces.ls="LS_"
resources.frontController.plugins.LangSelector="LS_Controller_Plugin_LangSelector"
```

What if now I want to change the location of my plugin to a place outside the zend-library?
what's the magic-words I should add to my config file?

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 0):

In your index.php

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/your new path containing the plugin',
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

Make sure you follow the Namespace when creating the class :)

Comment: I want to edit just the config file..do you think is possible ?:)

Comment: @luca worth a read go thru it..:)
http://blog.ekini.net/2009/06/04/registering-your-custom-plugins-in-zend-framework-18/

Comment: it does not talk about path outside of the library